# How to get event by id from vuex and open in detail page

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vuex

i am continuing this app [Read data from firebase in vuex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61001363/read-data-from-firebase-in-vuex/61004305#61004305). I got stuck when i want open a details page with a event. Until now i could did is, when for the first time i click on an event it’s open a details page of the event clicked with an error in the console, but when i reload the detail page, it doesn’t reload data.

This is my store.js

```
 state:{
        events:[],
    },

    mutations:{
        setEvent(state,payload){
            state.events = payload
        },

        setEventDetails(state,payload){
          state.events = payload
        },
    },

    actions:{
        addEvent(context,payload){
            firebase.database().ref('eventos/').push(payload)
                .then((event)=>{
                    context.commit('setEvent',event)
                }).catch(err =>{
                console.log(err)
            })
        },

        getEvents({commit}){
            let events = [];

            firebase.database().ref('eventos')
                .on('value',event =>{
                    event.forEach(data =>{
                        events.push({ "id": data.key, ...data.val() })

                    });

                    commit('setEvent',events)
                });
        },

        getEventDetails(context,payload){
            let event = context.getters.eventDetails(payload.id);
            context.commit('setEventDetails',event)
        }

    },
     getters:{

         eventDetails: (state) => (id) => {
             return state.events.find((event) => event.id === id);
         },

         eventList: state => {
             return state.events
         },


     }
```

This is my ReadEvents.vue from where i click to open in details page a event.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="(event,id) in eventList" :key="id">
            {{event}}
            <button v-on:click="openEventDetails(event.id)">Details</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>

<script>

    export default {
        name: "ReadEvents",

        computed:{
            eventList(){
                return  this.$store.getters.eventList;
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            this.$store.dispatch('getEvents')

        },

        methods:{
            openEventDetails(id){

                this.$router.push({
                    name: 'Detalles',
                    params:{id:id}
                })
            }
        }
```

And this is the EventDetails.vue where render the details of a event.

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{search}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>


    export default {
        props:['id'],
        name: "EventDetails",

        computed:{
            search() {
                return this.$store.getters.eventDetails(this.id)
            },
        },


        created() {
            console.log(this.search)
        },

        mounted() {
            this.$store.dispatch('getEventDetails')
        },
    }
```

Here is a result when i open from ReadEvents.vue 
[image]

And this if after reload the page

[image]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFaB5.png):

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `this.$store.dispatch('getEvents')` from `mounted` in ReadEvents.vue.

But you don't do the same in `EventDetails.vue`. This means that when you navigate directly to the route that uses `EventDetails.vue` the vuex store is not populated with events.

One solution would be to create an action that gets an event's details and call it from `EventDetails.vue` mounted method.

Comment: Hi, do you think that if I use local storage to save the event, I would lose the grace of using the database?

Comment: That's not gonna work all the time. This will work for a user that has already seen that event, but sharing a link will not work as there's nothing in their localStorage.

Comment: As you said One solution....., i have tried this if you see in my screen shot. When i reload the page, it lost everything